# Cauchy Riemann of $\tan(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

So, I have to see if the Cauchy-Riemann condition holds for $\tan(z)$. To do this I have to get it into the form $u+iv$

This is what I have so far,

$$\tan(z) = \tan(x+iy) = \frac{\tan(x)+\tan(iy)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(iy)}.$$

Then I tried setting $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(2x)}{1+\cos(2x)}$ and similarly for $\tan(iy)$ but I get stuck. So a hint on how to continue from $\frac{\tan(x)+\tan(iy)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(iy)}$ would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you use that $\tan z =\frac{\sin z}{ \cos z}$ so since the function is the division of two analytic functions hence analytic away from the zeros of the denmoniator?
Hence the CR are satisfied except at zeros of $\cos z$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\tan(iy) = \frac{\sin(iy)}{\cos(iy)}$. We know that

$$\sin(iy) = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{-y}-e^y) = i\sinh(y).$$

Likewise,

$$\cos(iy) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{-y}+e^y) = \cosh(y).$$

So we have that

$$\tan(z) = \frac{\tan(x)+i\tanh(y)}{1-i\tan(x)\tanh(y)}.$$

Can you see where to go from here? (Hint: try multiplying by a clever form of $1$...)